# Black Screen with an underscore at the top left of screen

Tags: boot, black-screen

I remember locking the laptop with Super+L and after I return and open it, it shows me the above mentioned black screen. So I forced shutdown and now restarting it always gives me black screen with an underscore(_).

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing but mine had to do with adding a 5600 xt and the radeon drivers in 5.3 not working. Installing 5.4 fixed the issue. Too do this boot to 5.1 and install ukuu and use it too install 5.4 I haven't tried 5.5.